# XtraRichEdit - Programmatically change input font color

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, richedit

Is it possible to programmatically change current font color in the document?

By this I don't mean changing color of specific selection of the document. I need to have all text written by user in blue color. Is it possible to programmatically change input color to blue?

I tried using the `ChangeFontColorCommand`, but I couldn't find the right way to use it. This code simulates the command used by toolbar button:

```
var command = new ChangeFontColorCommand(RichEdit);
var uiState = (IValueBasedCommandUIState<Color>) command.CreateDefaultCommandUIState();
uiState.EditValue = Color.Blue;
command.ForceExecute(uiState);
```

**Is it possible to have all text written by user in blue?** How? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does the [Document.DefaultCharacterProperties](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraRichEditAPINativeDocument_DefaultCharacterPropertiestopic) property suits your needs?
Please try the following:

```
richEditControl.Document.DefaultCharacterProperties.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Sadly, this property changes nothing at all. I think it only changes the default format. That means that the text will be blue only when I select it and apply ClearFormattingCommand.